# Adding ssl certificate to helm chart

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, tls1.2

I have added an ssl cert secret in rancher and configured the ingress file in the helm chart as follows:

```
{{- $fullName := include "api-chart.fullname" . -}}
{{- $ingressPath := .Values.ingress.path -}}
{{- $apiIngressPath := .Values.ingress.apiPath -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "api-chart.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "api-chart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
{{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
      secretName: {{ .Values.ssl.certSecretName }}
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ $ingressPath }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: 80
          - path: {{ $apiIngressPath }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: 8080
```

The default, fake, Nginx certificate is however still received when visiting the https site. Does the Nginx server also need to be changed? If so seems strange that it is a requirement to add the certificate info in two places. If not, what else could be wrong?

`kubectl describe ingress` gives the following response:

```
Name:             my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.240.0.4
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                                    Path  Backends
  ----                                    ----  --------
  project-jupyter-labs-2.company.com  
                                          /test72-new-user   my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs:80 (10.244.4.20:8888)
                                          /base-url          my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs:8080 (10.244.4.20:8080)
Annotations:
  field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:              [{"addresses":["10.240.0.4"],
                                                  "port":80,
                                                  "protocol":"HTTP",
                                                  "serviceName":"default:my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs",
                                                  "ingressName":"default:my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs",
                                                  "hostname":"project-jupyter-labs-2.company.com",
                                                  "path":"/test72-new-user",
                                                  "allNodes":false},
                                                 {"addresses":["10.240.0.4"],
                                                  "port":80,
                                                  "protocol":"HTTP",
                                                  "serviceName":"default:my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs",
                                                  "ingressName":"default:my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs",
                                                  "hostname":"project-jupyter-labs-2.company.com",
                                                  "path":"/base-url",
                                                  "allNodes":false}]
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                  nginx
  meta.helm.sh/release-name:                    my-test-install-app72
  meta.helm.sh/release-namespace:               default
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size:  2G
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  81s                nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs
  Normal  CREATE  81s                nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs
  Normal  UPDATE  23s (x2 over 23s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs
  Normal  UPDATE  23s (x2 over 23s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs
```

UPDATE:
I am having trouble accessing the error logs. It seems like you need to exec into the container as root to be able to see these. What I did find however is that the server section of the nginx.conf file contains the following:

```
ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {                                                                                                                   
                        certificate.call()                                                                                                                       
                }
```

If I change this to ssl_certifacte and ssl_certifacte_key paths to the cert and key files that I manually added to the container, then it works.
Does the above `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` look normal for the ingress.yaml file? If so, what else could be the problem? If not, what could be causing this to not be probably configured?

Applying the following patch seems to allow the correct SSL certificate to be made available for https:

```
kubectl patch ingress <app-instance-name> -p '{"spec":{"tls":[{"hosts":["project-jupyter-labs-2.company.com"], "secretName": "tls-secret-name"}]}}'
```

Why this solves the problem is still unclear to me. I would appreciate any possible explanations.

Comment: Can you update your question with nginx controller logs and describe your ingress object (`kubectl describe ingress`)?

Comment: Can you also apply a dummy patch in order to reload ingress controller by using `kubectl patch ingress myingress -p '{"metadata":{"labels":{"dummy":"some_unique_new_value"}}}'
`.

Comment: I have updated the post with the ingress description

Comment: ejlouw, and what do say the most recent log entries of Ingress Controller after patching your existing 'my-test-install-app72-project-jupyter-labs' ingress resource, as @acid_fuji suggested ?

Comment: The patches do not appear to be showing in the logs anymore? I will investigate this further and update the post

Comment: Please see the latest update.

Comment: @acid_fuji, I applied the patch and confirmed that it appeared in the `kubectl describe ingress` (although I couldn't see the labels in the description, so I patched the annotations instead).

Comment: I have updated the post with a patchy solution. The real reason for the unexpected performance is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Applying the following patch seems to allow the correct SSL
>   certificate to be made available for https:
>
> ```
> kubectl patch ingress <app-instance-name>  -p '{"spec":{"tls":[{"hosts":["project-jupyter-labs-2.company.com"], "secretName": "tls-secret-name"}]}}'
> ```
>
> Why  this solves the problem is still unclear to me. I would
>   appreciate any possible explanations.

It's nearly impossible to deduce it, without having a minimal reproducible example from you.  Have a look how should [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) look like.

We know nothing about your resulting Ingress manifest file (generated by helm), Ingress Controller version and its configuration (including way of installation), and underlying Kubernetes environment.

**Just few hints:**

Please remember that Ingress/Secret resources are namespaced objects, and so in your case Ingress should reference secret from the same namespace. 
How exactly do you create a TLS secret ?

I can assure you that your case can be reproduced in healthy Ingress Controller setup, and whenever I create secret referenced by Ingress in right namespace, it's automatically detected by controller, added to a local store,  and  dynamic reconfiguration takes place.

Lastly I think your issue is more suitable to be reported directly Nginx  Ingress  Controller github's project: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/new